# Enforce excess property check on function return type?

Tags: typescript

In the following example, TypeScript compiler will not complain about returning an object of type `UserProfile` from a function that has a return type `UserProfileWithNoPermissions`:

```
interface UserProfile {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    permissions: string[],
}

type UserProfileWithNoPermissions = Omit<UserProfile, 'permissions'>

const getUser = (): UserProfileWithNoPermissions => {
    const profile: UserProfile = ({
        name: '',
        age: 0,
        permissions: ['canView'],
    })

  return profile

};
```

I understand that this is because of TS skipping excess property check in this case (as opposed to object literal for example).
But (subjectively) such code looks strange... Is there any relatively non-hacky way to make TS compiler complain about `profile` object having `permissions` property? Is it even a good idea to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPC comes into play just for fresh objects:

```
interface UserProfile {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    permissions: string[],
}

type UserProfileWithNoPermissions = Omit<UserProfile, 'permissions'>

const getUser = (): UserProfileWithNoPermissions => {
    return {
        name: '',
        age: 0,
        permissions: ['canView'], // <-- EPC error
    })
};
```

Therefore I think you'd need [exact types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly forbid the property `permissions` from appearing in an object with the `UserProfileWithNoPermissions` type.

```
type UserProfileWithNoPermissions = 
  Omit<UserProfile, 'permissions'> & { permissions?: undefined }
```

Though this will not check for any other *excess properties*.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoAUoHsbAA2KA3gFDKXIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYA0FVc7j1AK60ARtG5VkAB2i1g6dMFwh0TFmxDsA2gF1uAXzJkwATxlpMUHPiIQA6sDAALAHK4ss+YuXpkAXmQAeTkwAB4MbDwCYk5kAHIZKDkFJRU4gD5kADJkEmlPFJ8AfiZBEAATCAIQCHLkQzIEHzBkfjAIqH9kAAoASiYO62j7R1d3Au8Vf0zySSaVFqko2wHLIdsu7tnJKhp6Jji4iR3KPgEABmOTxOTJ1WQtOIQ4EAA1YAgAdzi9Hkp9XpGShQCBgQRQEDSZbEMj6ADcQA)